# For any given $n$, there are either infinitely many primitive Pythagorean triangles with one side $n$ units shorter than the hypotenuse, or none

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Prove that if there is at least one primitive Pythagorean triangle where one side is $n$ units less than the hypotenuse, then there are infinitely many.

I thought of looking at $X^2+Y^2=Z^2$ and setting $Z=X+n$ so $X^2+Y^2=(X+n)^2$
Then $X^2+Y^2=x^2+2Xn+n^2$ but this doesn't really help at all so I'm not sure how to prove this.

Comment: Do you know the formulas $x=2mn$, $y=m^2-n^2$, $z=m^2+n^2$ for these triangles?

Comment: Um, yes I know that that would be true. How do I use that?

Comment: So, that tells you something about the difference between a side and the hypotenuse, and it should be easy from there.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Um... well it tells me that $Z-Y=2n^2$ and $Z-X=(m-n)^2$ but I'm not sure how to use this to show there are infinitely many, so I think I am missing something.

Comment: So, for example, the difference is 8 if and only if $n=2$ --- that gives infinitely many. The difference is 9 if and only if $m-n=3$ --- that gives infinitely many. In general, ....